# Accessing an object with multiple generic data in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I wanna access two properties of an object same time. my code is

In the function of a controller

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> category = new    
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>();
Dictionary<int, string> Question_list = new Dictionary<int, string>();
List<int> ID = new List<int>();

Question_list.add(1, "Question 1");
Question_list.add(2, "Question 2");
Question_list.add(3, "Question 3");

category.add("one" , Question_list);

Id.add(27)

ViewBag.data = new { category , Id);
return View();
```

Now In Razor view

```
<table class="table" id="Evaluation_Question_Table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Questions
    </th>

    <th>
        Assessment
    </th>

</tr>

@foreach (var data in ViewBag.questionData)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center text-bold">
            @data.category.Key 
        </td>

        <td></td>
    </tr>


    foreach (var item in data.category.Value)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Value
            </td>

            <td class="form-group">

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select class="form-control" id='@item.Key' name="answers">
                        <option value="a">a</option>
                        <option value="b">b</option>
                        <option value="c">c</option>
                        <option value="d">d</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td>
            Teacher Comments
        </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea id="data.Id" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="col-md-offset-1 btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

In the id of textarea i wanna print the data of my int list but foreach is not working with such type of data.

how can I do this?

Comment: why don't you make a viewmodel and pass this viewmodel to view instead of `ViewBag.data` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this model:

```
Public class ViewModelSample 
{
   Public string Name { get; set; }
   Public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

after that change your dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<ViewModelSample, Dictionary<int, string>> category = new    
Dictionary<ViewModelSample, Dictionary<int, string>>();
```

then add like this:

```
Question_list.add(1, "Question 1");
Question_list.add(2, "Question 2");
Question_list.add(3, "Question 3");

category.add(new ViewModelSample {
Name = "one",
Id = 27
} , Question_list);
```

You can find your Id in the foreach -> **data.Key.Id and for also data.Key.Name**

Answer (score 0):

Make a ViewModel like this:

```
Public class ViewModelSample 
{
   Public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> category { get; set; }
   Public List<int> Id { get; set; }
}
```

then:

```
ViewBag.data = new ViewModelSample { 
   category = category,
   Id = Id
};
```

Don't forget cast your data in razor

```
var data = ViewBag.data as ViewModelSample;
```

Comment: i thought about it but it won't allow me to run category and Id at a same time in foreach.

Comment: i have an another solution for you. wait a min.

Comment: I wanna add the Id in the id of text-area with the dictionary data in sequence

Comment: I've put a new answer for you.